# Drupal 6 custom module redirect to mainpage if access denied

Tags: drupal, redirect, drupal-6

I'm interested in creating drupal forms and pages that if 'Access denied' is true, then they are automatically redirected to the main page. These forms and pages already hold _perm functions that have been defined by user type.

Is this possible? If so, how? and what are some resources for figuring this out?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to redirect user to login page since you want only a authenticated user to access that page. So redirect user to login page and add destination after he/she logs in.

Here, you can use this module : http://drupal.org/project/r4032login

Comment: i know how to re-direct to the login page, but that isn't what i wanted. thanks